# Actionscript problem in addChild

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var bin:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cir:Sprite = new Sprite();

cir.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00,1);
cir.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);
cir.graphics.endFill();

bin.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
bin.graphics.drawRoundRect(40,40,100,100,5,5);
bin.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bin);
bin.addChild(cir);
```

//Here why do the circle added outside the square box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your draw fnctions:

```
drawCircle(x, y, radius)
drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height...)
```

So circle's center is placed at 0,0 point and have 30px radius, rectangle starts at 40,40, so it starts further than cirle ends. 
ou cound rather try:

```
drawCircle(90, 90, radius)
drawRoundRect(40, 40, 100, 100...)
```

to have a circle in the middle of rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Because you add your rectangle a x:40/y:40 but your circle at x:0/y:0

```
var bin:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cir:Sprite = new Sprite();

cir.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00,1);
cir.graphics.drawCircle(40,40,30);
cir.graphics.endFill();

bin.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
bin.graphics.drawRoundRect(40,40,100,100,5,5);
bin.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bin);
bin.addChild(cir);
```

Works fine

Comment: But I have added the "cir" sprite within the "bin" sprite. Its okay.
Let me know that, what is the diff b/w applying x,y pos within and outside?

bin.graphics.drawRoundRect(40,40,100,100,5,5); 
//
bin.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,100,100,5,5);
bin.x = bin.y =  40;

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is added outside the box is the drawRoundRect still creates the sprite at 0,0 on the stage but doesn't start the fill until 40,40. You can check this out by tracing out the bin x and y properties to see they start at 0,0 and width and height properties to see that they are both 100 and not 60. You might have better luck drawing all the objects from 0,0 and then just adjusting the parent DisplayObject like the following:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var bin:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cir:Sprite = new Sprite();

bin.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
bin.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,60,60,5,5);
bin.graphics.endFill();

cir.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00,1);
cir.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);
cir.graphics.endFill();

addChild(bin);
bin.addChild(cir);
bin.x = bin.y = 40; //move the parent object, all child objects will move with it
```